# how to read json data from test.properties where other webelements exists

Tags: java, json

I've some WebElements in test.properties file and I need to read and store all the json data from that file. Can anyone please help in reading all the json data from properties file in java.

I've tried all the way of reading and storing the data but no luck.

**Here is my webElements in properties file:**

```
mprHomePageLogo=//span[@class='si mpr-logo-h40px' and text()='MyPerfectResume.com']
mprHomePageLogoNewLP=//*[@class='inner-container']/span[@class='logo']
textLabel1=//*[@id='mt_mac_headline']/h1[text()='The Online Resume Builder So Easy to Use']
headingTextLabelOnNewLP=//*[contains(@class,'h1') and contains(text(),'Your Resume, Made')]/../h1/span[text()='Easy']
textLabel2=//*[text()='My Perfect Resume takes the hassle out of resume writing. Easy prompts help you create the perfect job-worthy resume effortlessly!']
desktoplikeImageOnLP=//object[contains(@class,'hero-desktop')]/following-sibling::a
iconsAndArrows=//*[@id='page-header-ctnr']/ul/li[@id="icon1" and @class="icon-ctnr"]/following-sibling::li[@id="arrow1" and @class="arrow-ctnr"]/following-sibling::li[@id="icon2" and @class="icon-ctnr"]/following-sibling::li[@id="arrow2" and @class="arrow-ctnr"]/following-sibling::li[@id="icon3" and @class="icon-ctnr"]
jsonArray= {"card":[{"Name":"1test1","place":"1placetest1"},{"Name":"2test2","place":"placetest2"},{"Name":"3test3","place":"3placetest3"}]}
textLabel3532=//*[text()='My Perfect Resume takes the hassle out of resume writing. Easy prompts help you create the perfect job-worthy resume effortlessly!']
desktoplikeImageOtestnLP=//object[contains(@class,'hero-desktop')]/following-sibling::a
jsonArray2= {"card":[{"Name":"test1","place":"placetest1"},{"Name":"test2","place":"placetest2"},{"Name":"test3","place":"placetest3"}]}
```

As you can see there are two json data in this properties file(jsonArray & jsonArray2) and I need to read all keys and values of this jsonArray.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you need to read the values from your file. This can be done with following code using standart java packages

```
try {
        Properties prop = new Properties();
        String propFileName = "test.properties";
        inputSecretStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propFileName);
        if (inputSecretStream != null) {
            prop.load(inputSecretStream);
        } else {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("property file '" + propFileName + "' not found in the classpath");
        }

        String jsonArray = prop.getProperty("jsonArray");
        String jsonArray2= prop.getProperty("jsonArray2");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Exception: " + e);
    } finally {
        inputSecretStream.close();
    }
```

Then you should parse your JSON. I'm using Google's library Gson for that. It should look something like this

```
        JsonArray jarray = new JsonParser().parse(jsonArray ).getAsJsonArray();
        JsonObject jobject = jarray.getAsJsonObject("Name");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Ravi : you need gjson lib to parse the json data as @Sympth explained in above solution. 
Please find the below solution , Here I am reading data as InputFile.properties data and parsing it and storing it in HashMap.

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Properties;

import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonElement;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class JsonParserUtility {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            HashMap<String,String>jsonMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
            JsonParserUtility jsonParserUtility = new JsonParserUtility();
            String filePath = "$PLEASE PROVIDE properties file path here";
            //e.g. /Users/maheshjoshi/Desktop//InputFile.properties
            Properties prop = new Properties();
            FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            // load a properties file
            if (input != null) {
                prop.load(input);
            }
            String jsonArray1 = prop.getProperty("jsonArray");
            String jsonArray2= prop.getProperty("jsonArray2");

            jsonMap.putAll(jsonParserUtility.parseJsonDataAndFetchAllValues(jsonArray1));
            jsonMap.putAll(jsonParserUtility.parseJsonDataAndFetchAllValues(jsonArray2));

            int count = 0;
            for (String key : jsonMap.keySet()) {
                count++;
                System.out.println(count+". key : "+key+" value : "+jsonMap.get(key));
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    /**
     * @param String : partialJsonData
     * @return hasmap with all key elements
     * */

    private  HashMap<String,String> parseJsonDataAndFetchAllValues(String partialJsonData) {
        HashMap<String,String>jsonMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
        JsonElement jelement = null;
        JsonObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
            jelement = jsonParser.parse(partialJsonData);
            jsonObject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();

            jsonObject = new JsonParser().parse(partialJsonData).getAsJsonObject();
            JsonArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getAsJsonArray("card");
            for (Object object : jsonArray) {
                JsonObject aJson = (JsonObject) object;
                String name = aJson.getAsJsonPrimitive("Name").toString().replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
                String place = aJson.getAsJsonPrimitive("place").toString().replaceAll("^\"|\"$", "");
                //System.out.println(name);
                //System.out.println(place);
                jsonMap.put(name, place);
            }           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return jsonMap;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @param fileName
     * @return string data 
     * @throws IOException
     */
    public String readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
        StringBuilder sb = null;
        try {
            sb = new StringBuilder();
            String line = br.readLine();

            while (line != null) {
                sb.append(line);
                line = br.readLine();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: welcome @ravi.. if you problem is resolved you can mark this anwser as accepted. with selection . thanks in advance.